# What does the $e$ operation mean in cryptography research papers?

Tags: hash, authenticated-encryption

I read a cryptography scheme that it include the following operation:

$$c= H(e(g_1,g_n)^t)$$
where H is a hash function.
I need to know what the operation $e$ means.

Comment: Actually, as far as I know, all articles have some explanation. Boneh et al's 2DNF explains very well. [Evaluating 2-DNF Formulas on Ciphertexts](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/2dnf.pdf). Where did you read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the pairing function. This bilinear map which takes as input an element from the set $\mathbb{G}\times\hat{\mathbb{G}}$ (in the common case, elliptic curves), and outputs a group element in $\mathbb{G}_T$, the target group.

In the symmetric case (Type 1), because $e$ is bilinear, you can deduce that $$e(g_1, g_n)^t= e(g, g)^{x_1x_nt}$$

with $x_1,x_n$ respectively the discrete logarithms of $g_1, g_n$ in base $g$.

For more details check:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing-based_cryptography

Comment: Note that It is not limited to elliptic curves. It is a general map.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly the bilinear map do in this computation if we suppose that e is a bilinear  map  $G$ X $G$ -> $G_T$  and $G , G_T$ are two cyclic groups of prime order p and g is a random generator for G

Comment: @kiukige is it better?